# 'cascading' resource bundles flex/AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, resources

I have an adobe Air App that uses localization.  The app uses the resources defined in `/locale/en_US/resources.properties` by default, but the user can switch to french via a flag in our data.

My question is rather simple, but I haven't been able to find relevant documentation...

I want the app to default to the resource entry in the `en_US` bundle if that particular entry is not found in the `fr_FR` bundle.

So if I call `{resourceManager.getString('resources','foo.bar')}` but `foo.bar` isn't defined in the French bundle (and the user logged in is french), it defaults to what I defined in the English one.

Has anyone made something like this work in an Air app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [localeChain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/resources/IResourceManager.html#localeChain) on `resourceManager` to an array where the first value is the primary language and the second is the fallback. Should be something like this:

```
resourceManager.localeChain = [ "fr_FR", "en_US" ];
```

This will tell Flex to first look for the key in the `fr_FR` resources and, if that doesn't exist, fall back to the `en_US` resources.

Comment: Hah it was staring at me right in the face! :)  And there I was, wondering why `localeChain` took an array as a parameter... Thanks!